# Could we keep the original question visible when improving edit in the Suggested Edits queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Occasionally in the [Suggested Edits review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/), someone has made a really great suggested edit except they have made a couple minor changes in the code, for example - adding a semicolon.

The problem is that this minor change could be the solution to the original poster's issue.

In cases like this I would

1. Roller-click the post title to have the original opened in one tab
2. Click "improve edit" to remove this added semi-colon.
3. Leave a comment explaining that there is a semi-colon missing in their code.

When it is just one semi-colon, this flow works pretty well, but when there are several in a long code excerpt, it gets a little confusing trying to get all those little mis-corrected typos put back in the right place.

What would be really nice, in my opinion, would be to have the side-by-side diff whilst improving an edit to simplify this task.  I'm also curious how do others deal with this type of thing.

Comment: I do pretty much the exact same thing though what I usually see is an edit that's 98% good except a change to the text itself that made it slightly worse  (less clear) or potentially changed a sentence's meaning. The ability to see the original version would be useful in these cases (though I wouldn't want the diff visible the whole time due to limited space).

Comment: I agree, occasionally it is text as well.  And you're right about limited space.  I think the diff and/or original post would have to be below where there is currently the preview of your modifications.